# Hibernate criteria query using Projections.rowCount() causes a numeric overflow

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jdbc

I'm using Oracle 11g R2. I have a table with 9.1 billion rows. When I try to run a criteria query which contains `Projections.rowCount()` (which I need to do to get the number of rows in the table) using either `.list()` or `.uniqueResult()`, I get a Numeric Overflow exception.

The relevant part of the stack trace:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Numeric Overflow
  oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAcessor?throwOverFlow
  oracle.jdbc.driver.NumberCommonAcessor?getInt
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl?getInt
  oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSet?getInt
  org.hibernate.type.IntegerType?get  <---------------- oops.
  org.hibernate.type.NullableType?nullSafeGet
  org.hibernate.type.NullableType?nullSafeGet
  org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader?getResultColumnOrRow
  org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet
  org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery
  org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections
  org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList
  org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache
  org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list
  org.hibernate.loader.criteria.CriteriaLoader?list
  org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl?.list
  org.hibernate.impl.CriteriaImpl?.list
  mypackage.myclass.GetRowCount
```

Hibernate is deciding to use an Integer to store the result regardless of the table size. How can I override this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [SQLProjection](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/criterion/SQLProjection.html) using a return `Type` large enough for your result.

Comment: This seems to have fixed it. Instead of using `criteria.setProjection(Projections.rowCount())` I'm using `criteria.setProjection(new SQLProjection("count(*) as ROWCOUNT", new String[]{"ROWCOUNT"}, new Type[]{new LongType()})`